# cakephp - get results from two unrelated tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I've been googling this for a while but to no avail. I'm finding the possible answers confusing and hoped someone could clear it up for me.

I've two tables (tasks and installs) which contain similar data, but not the same, and there's no relationship between the two tables, other than the fact they both belong to the same branch. So for example:

**Tasks Table**

```
id  
branch_id  
task_name  
to_be_billed   
created
```

**Installs Table**

```
id  
branch_id  
install_details  
to_be_billed   
created
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a result set which would show each record from either table, arranged by date created order and only where the 'to_be_billed' column is '1'.

Can anyone give me some pointers please?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you _could_ write a JOIN on these conditions and see what it gives you.. is the date with time or without? And how man records in both tables?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to get the results using the branch_id and these two tables (Tasks and Install) have some relationship with the BranchTable.

I'm also assuming the Tasks and Installs Table's have multiple records for a Branch.

```
BranchTable->find()
    ->contain([
        'Tasks' => [
            'sort' => ['Tasks.created' => 'ASC'] 
        ]
    ])
    ->contain([
        'Installs' => [
            'sort' => ['Installs.created' => 'ASC'] 
        ]
    ])
    ->matching('Tasks', function ($q){
        return $q->andWhere(['Tasks.to_be_billed' => 1]);
    })
    ->matching('Installs', function ($q){
        return $q->andWhere(['Installs.to_be_billed' => 1]);
    })
    ->where(['Branch.id' => $foo]);
```

If your doubt does not use these assumptions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the data using one DB query then you would need to use the UNION operator.

In that case you would need these two queries to have the same columns, so for example:

```
select 
   id,
   branch_id,
   task_name,
   NULL as install_details,
   'task' as type,
   to_be_billed,
   created
from 
   tasks_table
UNION
select 
   id,
   branch_id,
   NULL as task_name,
   install_details,
   'install' as type,
   to_be_billed,
   created
from 
   install_table
```

but that's a rather dirty solution.

If I knew what exactly you are trying to achieve, maybe I could suggest a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically I'm trying to get a result set which combines the two tables information together. The column names don't have to be the same. I'm wondering if it's a better idea to just do two seperate queries, one for each table, and then sort the results of each in a foreach so I can sort them by date.

Comment: Yes, you also can merge the results of the two separate queries into one array and then sort it using some callback function, for example (pseudo-code) `usort($array, function($a, $b) {return $a->created->getTimestamp() > $b->created->getTimestamp()})`

Comment: Yes, this seems to me like a problem to solve after retrieving data from the database, not in the query itself.